# Невозможно вызвать функцию

Tags: c++, классы, функции, статические-члены

Написал вот такой код.

```
#include "object.h"
#include "model.h"
#include "sprite.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class load_manager {
        private:
                static std::map <std::string,Model  *> mmap;
                static std::map <std::string,Sprite *> smap;

                void get_view ( Sprite **view, std::string &path ) {
                        *view = smap [ path ];
                        if ( !*view ) {
                                *view = new Sprite ( );
                                (*view)->read_file ( path.c_str() );
                                smap [ path ] = *view;
                        }
                }
                void get_view ( Model **view, std::string &path ) {
                }
        public:
                static T *getModel ( const char *s ) {
                        std::string path ( s );
                        T *view;
                        get_view ( &view, path );

                        return view;
                }
};
```

Думал что можно хоть так указатель передать чтобы вызвать нужную функцию, но нет, пишет

```
In file included from ./src/menu/../engine.h:7:0,
                 from ./src/menu/menu.cpp:1:
./src/menu/../engine/load_manager.h: In instantiation of ‘static T* load_manager<T>::getModel(const char*) [with T = Sprite]’:
./src/menu/menu.cpp:42:29:   required from here
./src/menu/../engine/load_manager.h:27:13: error: cannot call member function ‘void load_manager<T>::get_view(Sprite**, std::__cxx11::string&) [with T = Sprite; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ without object
    get_view ( &view, path );
```

Можно ли как то сделать?

Comment: Как и когда пользоваться преимуществами наследования, как и когда пользоваться преимуществами шаблонов _ нужно знать

Answer (score 2):

А на что вы рассчитываете? Для **какого** объекта вы хотите вызывать `get_view`? Смотрите: ваша `getModel` описана как `static`, она по сути аналог свободной функции - вызывается не для конкретного объекта, а просто с указанием имени класса (действующего по сути как пространство имен) -

```
load_manager::getModel(...)
```

Ваша же `get_view` статической не является и должна вызываться с указанием объекта класса, для которого ее следует вызвать, вроде

```
load_manager l, *pl;

l.get_view(...);
pl->get_view(...);
```

Так что либо - если ваша `get_view()` не зависит от объекта класса, делайте ее статической, либо указывайте объект, для которого она должна вызываться, либо делайте нестатической `getModel` - все зависит от того, что вам нужно...

Comment: Кроме того  get_view  может вызываться только  если  T  это  Model. Так что эту функцию нужно определять только для фул специализации:  template<>  load_manager<Model>.  И для чего вы так настырно хотите, чтобы класс был шаблонным, непонятно....